# Parse Query most recent objects whereKey("pageNumber", equalTo: number)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have a Parse class called `Book`. Inside it is a column `pageNumber`.

I want to query the most recent objects for each page number. There can be more than one object with the same `pageNumber` which is why I only want to query the most recent object for each value under `pageNumber`.

So, if there are six different objects with a value of (4) under `pageNumber` in the class `Book` how would I get just the most recently created object. Not just for `pageNumber` (4) but for all unique `pageNumbers` 1-50.

Answer (score 0):

For a specific page number :

You should order the result by createdAt date, and set the limit of the query to 1 :

```
query.descending("createdAt"); 
query.limit(1);
```

For each page number, you can either iterate on every possible page number value, or retrieve everything and iterate other the results, selecting the most recent object for the same page number (using a hash table)

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by "iterate on every possible page number value"... But the hash table solution is what I currently have implemented I was wondering if it was possible to do it in the query itself.